# Development cross-platform android application

Tags: android, cross-platform

I am developing an Android application and using my HTC Wildfire phone for testing the app.
I wonder something, will it be possible for a Samsung  Galaxy user (or another phone user) use my app, or do I have to do alter the app to run on other Android devices?

Comment: If you need a very good set of examples, tutorials etc, you better search in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). However, this is not called cross-platform. 
You have a bad news. You can code perfectly according to the SDK documentation but still some things might not work as expected on some devices. So, you also need to test on as many devices as you can.

Comment: bread and butter stuff works mostly as expected.  most  differences are  in sensors and camera handling.    sticking to specifications ususally helps, even is they do not make sense on first sight